# Is it possible to select the largest overlap of multiple polygons

Tags: sql-server-2008, geometry, geography

Working with a mapping tool that stores country shapes as SQL Server 2010 geometry and I have a use case where I need to select the polygon from a group of polygons that overlaps another polygon the most.

For example, on a map of Earth, we could draw an outline around the shape of France (overlapping Spain, Germany, and Italy) and the overlap would return Spain, Germany, Italy, and France and I need to have France returned (as it will have the largest overlap.)

I cannot find anything in the documentation covering a way to do this.  Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct api to get that but you could:

- calculate the various intersecting polygons with STIntersection ([http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933832(v=sql.110).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933832%28v=sql.110%29.aspx))
- order by their area using STArea and pick the first result ([http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933923(v=sql.110).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933923%28v=sql.110%29.aspx))